# What should be LAN speed?

Tags: networking, lan, transfer

I've got PC and laptop, both connected with wire to switch witch supports 1gb/s transfer. My download speed from Internet is about 800mb/s. On laptop is nvme type disk, on pc I've got SSD sata, Ubuntu 20.04 on both. When I'm downloading files using rsync download speed is about 20mb/s. I was hoping for maximum speed and certainly not so low ... is it possible?

Comment: You do realize the speed also depends on the upload connection from the server you get the file from?

Comment: Sure, but I gave the download value to show that the problem is definitely not the network card.
I'm sending files between my two computers which are in the same network, connected by cable to switch.

Comment: All devices in the chain need to support gigabit 10/1000 to get gigabit speeds. e.g. the wired network devices in both PCs and any switches inbetween. On both your PCs run the following to see what they support: `ethtool eth0` (change eth0 to the name of your wired network device `ifconfig` to list devices/names). Also how are you measuring the speed and what command are you using? What are you transferring to get the measurement, lots of files, one big file?